# upload resize image function php

Tags: php

I want to get this code working as described, it needs just to specify the path and I don't know where to add it.

This code is working will I want to add path to upload the image to specific folder ??

```
<?php

function image_resize($src, $dst, $width, $height, $crop=0){

  if(!list($w, $h) = getimagesize($src)) return "Unsupported picture type!";

  $type = strtolower(substr(strrchr($src,"."),1));
  if($type == 'jpeg') $type = 'jpg';
  switch($type){
    case 'bmp': $img = imagecreatefromwbmp($src); break;
    case 'gif': $img = imagecreatefromgif($src); break;
    case 'jpg': $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($src); break;
    case 'png': $img = imagecreatefrompng($src); break;
    default : return "Unsupported picture type!";
  }

  // resize
  if($crop){
    if($w < $width or $h < $height) return "Picture is too small!";
    $ratio = max($width/$w, $height/$h);
    $h = $height / $ratio;
    $x = ($w - $width / $ratio) / 2;
    $w = $width / $ratio;
  }
  else{
    if($w < $width and $h < $height) return "Picture is too small!";
    $ratio = min($width/$w, $height/$h);
    $width = $w * $ratio;
    $height = $h * $ratio;
    $x = 0;
  }

  $new = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

  // preserve transparency
  if($type == "gif" or $type == "png"){
    imagecolortransparent($new, imagecolorallocatealpha($new, 0, 0, 0, 127));
    imagealphablending($new, false);
    imagesavealpha($new, true);
  }

  imagecopyresampled($new, $img, 0, 0, $x, 0, $width, $height, $w, $h);

  switch($type){
    case 'bmp': imagewbmp($new, $dst); break;
    case 'gif': imagegif($new, $dst); break;
    case 'jpg': imagejpeg($new, $dst); break;
    case 'png': imagepng($new, $dst); break;
  }
  return true;
}

if(isset($_POST['submitButton'])){


   $picture=$_FILES['image1'];

   $pic_type = strtolower(strrchr($picture['name'],"."));
   $pic_name = "original$pic_type";
   move_uploaded_file($picture['tmp_name'], $pic_name);
   if (true !== ($pic_error = @image_resize($pic_name, "100x100$pic_type", 100, 100, 1))) {
    echo $pic_error;
     unlink($pic_name);
   }
   else echo "OK!";
  }
?>





<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

    <p>
        <input type="file" name="image1" />
    </p>

    <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="save"/>

</form>
```

I have solved this by adding the folder path to both $pic_name & "100x100$pic_type":)

Answer (score 0):

The first and second arguments of your 
`image_resize($src, $dst, $width, $height, $crop=0)` function take source path and destination path to picture respectively.

So in your code you should edit the following part:

```
$pic_name = "original$pic_type";
move_uploaded_file($picture['tmp_name'], $pic_name);
if (true !== ($pic_error = @image_resize($pic_name, "100x100$pic_type", 100, 100, 1))) {
```

Currently your source path is specified as `"original$pic_type"` and destination path is specified as `"100x100$pic_type"`, you may change it somehow you want.

Comment: your suggestion is not working when I run the code the first $pic_name  is the name of the orginal image with its orginal size and the second is the name for the small sized image "100x100$pic_type"

Comment: Yes, you can use something like `$path."100x100$pic_type"`

Comment: i edit zavg's post, you should use {} to add $vars to a string like $pic_name = "somename{$pic_type}";

Comment: I have solved this by adding the folder path to both $pic_name & "100x100$pic_type":)

Comment: Congrats, but isn't it exactly the same I wrote you?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['submitButton'])){
    //function image_resize($src, $dst, $width, $height, $crop=0)
    $tmpName = $_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'];
    image_resize($tmpName, '/where/you/want/your/file', 300, 300)
      // width and height just set a minimal width and height for the picture)
}
```

What you want is $dst, altrought, you can make this code better.

EDIT: you must specify a folder and a file name in the $dst, if you don`t know the file ext, you can add $dst as a folder, and inside the function you add a file name to it, like:
    $dst = "/myfolder/toupload/"
    $file = myfilename.".".$type 
    $dst .= $file;

Comment: I have solved this by adding the folder path to both $pic_name & "100x100$pic_type":)